# Single nuget.target file executed from multiple targets file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-server, nuget-cli

We have setup an internal nuget server. While setting things up we have several packages with .targets file which copies some dlls to output folder.

When we use these packages only the last nuget.target file (last package added) seems to be executing and copying the files to output folder.

Cant seem to figure this out as to why others wouldnt execute.

Any suggestion ?

EDIT:

Issue only arises during **Debug Configuration**.

Code below in csproj file...

```
 <Import Project="..\..\..\packages\Package2.1.0.3504\build\Package2.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\..\packages\Package2.1.0.3504\build\Package2.targets')" />
```

Nusepc file:

```
 <file src="buildTargets\Pack1.targets" target="build\Pack1.targets" />
<file src="dlls\external\x64\Pack1Proj\Pack1.dll" target="runtimes\x64\lib\net451\Pack1.dll" />
```

Targets file:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" >
    <Exec Command="xcopy /Y &quot;$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\runtimes\x86\lib\net451&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot;" />  
</Target>
```

Comment: @Stefan i have added the file as requested in the description. Having investigated furtehr it seems the issue arises during debug configuration only. In Release configuration it seems to work fine. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are there multiple imports or just one?

Comment: Are all targets named `AfterBuild`?

Comment: @MartinUllrich There are multiple imports. Yes, all targets are named AfterBuild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Targets using the same name overwrite each other. So if you have multiple

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
```

only one will be run - the one that is imported last. In fact, `AfterBuild` is an empty target defined in the common targets that is meant to be overwritten.

To make your targets compatible, use different methods to hook into this build step:

```
<Target Name="Package1AfterBuild" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
```

Comment: If i understand correctly then for each unique package i will need to have unique Name but can have same AfterTargets.

Comment: exactly. The name is the identity and the AfterTargets definition serves as your hook into the build logic.

Comment: thank you for you answer as it has now resolved my issue.